# What are the fire stones and trading floors in Ezekiel 28:11-19?

Tags: ezekiel

I do not understand the fire stones and trades Ezekiel 28:11-19

> **28**<sup>11</sup>   Moreover the word of the LORD came to me:
>   <sup>12</sup> "Son of man, raise a lamentation over the king of Tyre, and say to him,
>   Thus says the Lord GOD:
>   "You were the signet of perfection, full of wisdom and perfect in beauty.
>   <sup>13</sup> You were in Eden, the garden of God;
>         every precious stone was your covering, carnelian, topaz, and jasper, chrysolite, beryl,
>   and onyx, sapphire, carbuncle, and emerald;
>         and wrought in gold were your settings and your engravings.
>   On the day that you were created they were prepared.
>   <sup>14</sup> With an anointed guardian cherub I placed you; you were on the holy mountain of God;
>         in the midst of **the stones of fire** you walked.
>   <sup>15</sup> You were blameless in your ways from the day you were created,
>         till iniquity was found in you.
>   <sup>16</sup> In **the abundance of your trade** you were filled with violence, and you sinned;
>         so I cast you as a profane thing from the mountain of God,
>         and the guardian cherub drove you out from the midst of **the stones of fire.**
>   <sup>17</sup> Your heart was proud because of your beauty;
>         you corrupted your wisdom for the sake of your splendor.
>   I cast you to the ground;
>         I exposed you before kings, to feast their eyes on you.
>   <sup>18</sup> By the multitude of your iniquities, in the unrighteousness of **your trade**
>         you profaned your sanctuaries;
>   so I brought forth fire from the midst of you;
>         it consumed you, and I turned you to ashes upon the earth in the sight of all who saw you.
>   <sup>19</sup> All who know you among the peoples are appalled at you;
>         you have come to a dreadful end and shall be no more for ever."

Comment: Related:  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1682/what-are-the-stones-of-fire-in-ezekiel-28?rq=1

Comment: Please indicate what version you are citing; thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Verses 11-19 speaks of Satan himself, who was “created”, not born. He was the chief Cherub in all his beauty before being cast out. This is a symbolic reference to the King of Tyre, but does not speak of him in these versus. For the king of Tyre was born, and not in the garden. Nor was he a Cherub of the garden. Lay hold for just a minute on the versus, and how they describe something created by God in all its beauty and majesty, but then cast out of the garden to be consumed by the very fire inside of itself. This is when Satan was cast down....after his rebellion in the garden.

Comment: I have upvoted (the downvote is inappropriate) but scripture does not say the Serpent (not named, here, as Satan) was banished from the garden. The garden was an environment for humanity, not spirits.

Comment: @D.Grubbs. Thanks for the response. Here are some hints to help you in the future. This site is concerned with hermeneutics and addressing the specific issue the questioner addresses. In this case, the questioner was asking about "firestones and "trade".  So, our responses should address those questions specifically. Also, hermeneutics deals with grammar and context, so our answers should address the questioners specific questions from a grammatical and contextual point of view.

Answer (score 1):

This passage is not about the Satan but rather about the city of Tyre. Tyre was the main seaport on the east side of the Mediterranean sea. Ezekiel uses superlative figures to describe its wealth.

The "fiery stones" are the many jewels described in verse 13 that apparently adorned the city and would have been stunning and glorious with the sunlight reflecting back at it:

> 13 You were in Eden, the garden of God;
>         **every precious stone was your covering, carnelian, topaz, and jasper, chrysolite, beryl, and onyx, sapphire, carbuncle, and emerald;
>         and wrought in gold were your settings and your engravings.**

The trading floors were the expanses where business was conducted:

https://www.jetsetter.com/magazine/1549/must-see-spots-in-Nova-Scotia

Answer (score 0):

Thou hast been in Eden, the garden of God, Ezekiel 28:13.
Thou art the anointed cherub, 28:14.
Thou hast walked up and down in the midst of the stones of fire, 28:14.
Thou wast perfect till . . . iniquity was found in thee, 28:15.
I will destroy thee from the midst of the stones of fire, 28:16.

The Entity who appeared in Eden and who also, Job 2:1, was found among
the sons of God, was later cast out of heaven, Revelation 12:9.

Elsewhere, the angels, the sons of God (by creation) are described : who 
maketh his angels spirits and his ministers a flame of fire, Hebrews 1:7.

Thus I believe that the stones of fire are those also described as
flames of fire. In the context of Ezekiel 28, where the description
relates very much to the earthly effects of the Entity's power, 
stone is used as an analogy for stone lasts as long as Creation.

Whereas flame of fire is a more heavenly description, since no fuel
is mentioned, only flame itself.

Ezekiel 28 is addressed to the King of Tyre (an office) but is not
addressed, by name, to the person in that office. Thus I believe
that the office is to be seen prophetically and as an allusion.

The office was the most powerful one at that time, on earth, which
equates to the heavenly situation of the Entity, before the successful
campaign of Michael, and his support, rid heaven of the unwanted one.

Nigel.

Answer (score -1):

The Torah and some prophets including Ezekiel use a non-standard method of gematria that is sourced to the Wheel of the Chariot (a.k.a. the Seven Palaces).

The Wheel (and its gematria) looks like this:

[image: Ezekiel's Wheel]

Ezekiel also uses architectonic gematria that links the conformations of the Wheel/Seven Palaces to the Temple.

I've done the calculations up to line 14, but I haven't been able to work out what he's doing with 15-19 yet, however using the correct gematria as a method of exegesis should help you discover the meaning for yourself.  I recommend that you use the interlinear feature of [biblehub.com](http://biblehub.com/interlinear/ezekiel/28-1.htm) to work with the original hebrew (as I have done).

**Tyre** (‎צֹ֜ר‎ 290).
After rebuking the leader for his ‎excessive pride, Ezekiel starts to needle him ‎saying “Is no secret hidden from you?”  (28:3).  ‎Then in 28:13 Ezekiel numbers the Garden of ‎Eden to 265 which is the gate number of ‎Samekh on the 7 palaces and represents the ‎Solar radiance of God descending to the Temple ‎on Earth.  He then makes a list of 9 precious ‎stones, gold and two musical instruments and ‎these are meant to be added together and then ‎divided by 6.  The last is indicated by the final ‎phrase “on the day you were created they were ‎prepared” as all men were created on the 6th ‎day.  ‎

> 350 Sapphire + 220 Beryl + 45 Sardius + 98 ‎Topaz + 91 Diamond + 48
> Onyx + 104 Jasper ‎‎+ 150 Emerald + 312 Carbuncle + 20 Gold + ‎‎114
> Tabrets + 188 Pipes = 1740.
>
> ‎1740 / 6 = 290 = Tyre.

This would tend to suggest that the leader of ‎Tyre was initiated into the secret of the ‎Merkabah.  Additionally, the gate ‎number 265 may have indicated time conversion by ‎base 60, as Samekh is 60, and 1740 seconds is ‎‎29:00 minutes.  ‎

To save you some time I've numbered the following phrases for you:

> Ezekiel 28:14:
>
> כְּר֔וּב 228 ; Cherub
>
> מִמְשַׁ֖ח 91 ; anointed
>
> הַסּוֹכֵ֑ךְ 111 ; the covers
>
> בְּהַ֨ר + קֹ֤דֶשׁ + אֱלֹהִים֙ ; Mountain 207 + Holy 107 + Elohim 86 =
> 400
>
> הָיִ֔יתָ 29 ; you were
>
> אַבְנֵי 63 ; stones
>
> 4 אֵ֖שׁ ; fire
>
> הִתְהַלָּֽכְתָּ 68 ; you walked

Usually when scribes are laying out calculations and they say "in the midst" or "in the middle" they simply expect you to divide the sum they're referencing by 2 in order to half it, however it is not usual for scribes to work with fractions so I'm not sure what Ezekiel intended by the phrase "from the midst of the stones of fire".

"Stones of fire" adds up to 67 which is the same as הַשָּׂטָ֖ן‎ ‘Hassatan’ (67); the Satan.  If the stones of fire are metaphors for Satan it might explain line 15: "Perfect [was] you in your ways from the day you were created until was found iniquity in" but much more work needs to be done with this chapter before any firm conclusions can be made.

> Ezekiel 28:16
>
> בְּרֹ֣ב 204 ; By the abundance
>
> רְכֻלָּתְךָ֗ 274 ; of your merchandise/trade
>
> Note that 274 is a gate number on the Wheel, i.e. Resh + Ayin + Daleth = 274.

---

More information about the providence and origin of the Seven Palaces can be found with my answer on BH [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4933/meaning-of-et%D7%90%D7%AA-and-vet%D7%95%D6%B0%D7%90%D6%B5%D6%A5%D7%AA-in-genesis-11), and also on my profile as well as my website: bethshebaashe.com